# Executing last command in ksh

Tags: shell, ksh, sh

I am running Solaris and I was wondering how to run the last command with ksh.
I know that in bash/sh you can do "!!" for the last command and !-N for "N minus the last command."
What is the equivalent in KSH?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Typing `r` works for me in ksh.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`r`, or <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>.  Korn shell doesn't implement `csh`/`bash`-style history, but you can manipulate the command history with `fc` (`r` is an alias for an `fc` invocation), or with `set -o emacs` or `set -o vi` you can use editor commands to search and modify previous commands.

Comment: Perfect. The fc command is just what I was looking for. So fc -s -2 would execute the command before the last command?

Answer (score 2):

Use fc -s (SOME letter of last executed command)

like  if the last executed command was cat sample.txt

use fc -s ca